# Yii2 not catching fatal errors when error_reporting is set

Tags: php, yii2

When setting Yii2 to production mode in index.php -

```
defined('YII_DEBUG') or define('YII_DEBUG', false);
defined('YII_ENV') or define('YII_ENV', 'prod')
```

I have a logger, which correctly logs errors while in production mode, and prints out an appropriate error message on user page, but also show these error messages on notices (killing pages unnecessarily).
So, I set error_reporting in index.php -

```
error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_STRICT);
```

But this prevents Yii2 from catching errors at all, so that they don't get logged, and renders a blank page in the event of any error allowed by error_reporting. It prevents notices from killing the page, but logging quits working when I use error_reporting()

Is there a Yii2 appropriate way of doing this? Has anyone had this issue before? Thanks for all attempted solutions.

The error log configuration -

```
    $log['targets'][] = [
    'class' => 'understeam\slack\LogTarget',
    'exportInterval' => 1,
    'levels' => ['error', 'warning'],
    'except' => [
        'yii\i18n*',
        'yii\web\HttpException:404',
        'yii\web\HttpException:403',
        'yii\web\ForbiddenHttpException',
        'yii\web\NotAcceptableHttpException',
        'yii\base\InvalidRouteException'
    ],
];
```

The above is using the vendor package "understeam/yii2-slack": "~0.3"

Comment: Can you tell more about your logger? Does it use set_error_handler(), is it your own logger or yii2 internal logger? I had similar problem, may be this will help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35522669/yii2-use-error-handler-only-for-fatal-errors-or-specify-handled-error-types/35792347

Comment: Sorry I didn't include that.
I added it to the bottom of my question.

Comment: Well, seems that you need to replace yii\web\ErrorHandler with your own implementation or use set_error_handler() to register your own function, that would trigger Yii::warning() to send message to logs.

Comment: You are wrong, a log target don't "show" errors to users. Do you have any strange errorHandler component config ?

Comment: To make sure I was clear - This logger works correctly when in production mode. It only stops working when I set error_reporting() as shown above.

Comment: You don't have to set error reporting yourself, you should let Yii handle this... What do you mean by "stops working" ?

Comment: @soju maybe I missed something. How do I tell yii not to throw exceptions on php notices in production?

Comment: Well, you are right about notices, I don't have this kind of problem since I think it is really better to write code without notices...

Comment: @soju agreed, but when working with legacy code, it's hard to clean up everything that could produce warnings, and better send them to logs for investigation without interrupting page generation.

Comment: Robert, did you try my solution?

Answer (score 0):

It was interesting case for me, and I had [similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35522669/yii2-use-error-handler-only-for-fatal-errors-or-specify-handled-error-types/35792347), and I think there is no way to solve this with internal Yii2 ErrorHandler. So I decided to create a [package](https://github.com/cronfy/yii2-web-errorhandler) with extended ErrorHandler that I hope can solve your issue.

Install it:

```
php composer.phar require cronfy/yii2-web-errorhandler
```

Set error reporting to report all errors:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Configure error handler component in yii config:

```
'components' => [
    'errorHandler' => [
        'class' => 'cronfy\yii\web\ErrorHandler',
        'typesToExceptions' => YII_DEBUG ? E_ALL : false,
        'typesToLog' => E_ALL,
    ],

    // ... other components

],
```

With this configuration:

1. In DEBUG mode all errors will be logged AND converted to exceptions.
2. In PRODUCTION mode all errors will be logged too, but will NOT provide exceptions that would break page.

Comment: Sorry I haven't had time to test this yet. I'm going to try it out today or tomorrow. Thank you!